# Regularity of Topological Space $(\mathbb R,\tau)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that the topological space $(\mathbb R, \tau)$ is regular, where $\tau$ is all the subsets $U \subseteq \mathbb R$ open in $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology plus all the sets of the form for $U \cap \mathbb Q$. Note that $B_{r} (x) =  (x -r, x +r)$

---

> **My attempt:**  Let $p \in \mathbb Q$, $U$ open in $(\mathbb R,\tau)$ with $p \in U$ and let $V  \subseteq \mathbb R $
> open in $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology such that $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q \subseteq  V$. Then for every  $x \in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$, there exists $\varepsilon_x > 0$ such that
> $$ \bigcup_{x\in \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q} B_{\varepsilon_x}(x) \subseteq V.$$
>
> and between any to real numbers, there is a rational number, so
> $B_{\varepsilon_x}(x) \cap \mathbb Q \neq \emptyset$ and hence $V \cap
> \mathbb Q \neq \emptyset$.
>
> Now, if $U \subset \mathbb R$ then $U $ is either  $U$ is open in $\mathbb R$ with usual
> topology  or $U = G \cap \mathbb Q$ for some $G$ open in $\mathbb R$ with the
> usual topology
>
> **Case 1:** If $U$ is open in $\mathbb R$ with usual topology, then
> for every $u \in U$, there exists $\varepsilon_u > 0$ such that        $$ \bigcup_{u\in U}B_{\varepsilon_u}(u)\subseteq U,$$
>
> and between  every two rational numbers, there is an irrational
> number, that is, there exists $y \in V \cap B_{\varepsilon_u}(u) \neq
>  \emptyset$ for some $u \in U$
>
> **Case 2:** If $U  = G \cap \mathbb Q$ for any $u_1, u_2 \in G\cap Q$ with $u_1 < u_2$, then there
> exists $x \in V$  such that $u_1 \leq x \leq u_2$. Moreover, if $x  -\varepsilon_x \leq  u_1 $ and  $u_2 \leq x +\varepsilon_x $, then $U
>  \cap V \neq \emptyset$. Otherwise, there exists $u_1^\prime, u_2^\prime
>  \in B_{\varepsilon_x} (x)$ and again $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$. So
> $(\mathbb R,\tau)$ is **not regular**.

---

I am on the right track or is some clear misunderstanding? Also, the last part is very clunky, so I welcome suggestions on how to streamline it.

Comment: Why assume the irrationals are a subset of $V$ in the beginning?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ is closed in this space and I am using it as such

Comment: Are you sure the space is regular? It seems hard to separate $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ (which is closed in $\tau$) from $0 \notin \mathbb{P}$ using pairwise disjoint sets...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It is not regular. That is what I hope I proved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $\mathbb{P}$ (the irrationals) is closed in $\tau$. Suppose $0 \in U$ and $\mathbb{P} \subseteq V$ and both are open in $\tau$, and disjoint.

As $V$ contains the irrationals it is in particular Euclidean open (it's not of the new type).

Also, $0 \in (-\delta, \delta) \cap \mathbb{Q} \subseteq U$ for some $\delta>0$. Let $p$ be an irrational in $(-\delta, \delta)$. Then for some small open interval $I$ around $p$ inside $(-\delta, \delta)$ we have that $I \subseteq V$ (by openness of $(-\delta, \delta) \cap V$ in the Euclidean topology). But if $q$ is a rational inside $I$ (which exists) then this $q \in U \cap V$ showing that $U$ and $V$ cannot be disjoint after all, contradiction.

Comment: @MichaelCook I don't understand the structure of your proof, so I cannot say. It's unreadable.

Comment: What is unreadable about it?

Comment: @MichaelCook No clear structure. A proof should be a story, with a plot, not an experimental poem with random statements put after another.

Comment: I was trying to do it case-by-case

Comment: @MichaelCook Then make clear in advance what the cases are going to be, use itemisation to demarcate cases etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92087/discussion-between-michael-cook-and-henno-brandsma).