# The nature of neighborhood basis for each point of the following topology

Tags: general-topology

if I have a topology $\tau_2$ generated by $S = \tau_1 \cup \{\mathbb{Q}\}$ where $\tau_1$ is the standard topology on the real numbers, then would, for each point $x$, there exist a neighborhood basis $\mathcal{B}_x$ made of closed subset of $\tau_2$? My intuition says no for the following reason. Each element in $\tau_2$ would look like either $U \in \tau_1$ or $U \cap \mathbb{Q}$, meaning that a closed set would look like either $U'$ or $U' \cup \mathbb{Q}'$, so, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the only suitable candidate for $\mathcal{B}_x$ seems  $\{\{x\}\}$ as every neighborhood at $x$ contains $x$, but $\{x\}$ itself is not a neighborhood at $x$ and cannot be $\mathcal{B}_x$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Should $U \cap \Bbb{Q}$ be $U \cup \Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Do you think $U \cap \mathbb{R}$ should be $U \cup \mathbb{R}$? even if $S$ is a subbasis?

Comment: Well, no, but both should be options. The set $(-1, 1) \cup \Bbb{Q}$ is open in $\tau_2$, for example.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you so much, you are right. I apologise for writing $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}$ in my previous comment. Do you see any possibility of forming $\mathcal{B}_x$ consisting of closed subsets once considering $U \cup \mathbb{Q}$ as an open set too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper form for elements of $\tau_2$ are $V \cup (U \cap \Bbb{Q})$, where $U, V \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ are open; this is what we get from arbitrary unions of finite intersections of sets from $S$.

My intuition tells me that the distinction between a rational and irrational point will be significant here. Suppose $x \in \Bbb{Q}'$. Note that, if $x \in V \cup (U \cap \Bbb{Q})$, then $x \in V$. That is, given any neighbourhood $W$ of $x$ in $\tau_2$, there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ in $\tau_1$ such that $V \subseteq W$. That is, any local basis for $x$ in $\tau_1$ (including the set of closed balls around $x$) will be a local basis for $x$ in $\tau_2$. Therefore, for $x \in \Bbb{Q}'$, a local basis of closed neighbourhoods is perfectly possible (remember too that anything closed in $\tau_1$ is closed in $\tau_2$).

On the other hand, suppose $x \in \Bbb{Q}$. Note that the same trick doesn't work here. If we choose the local basis of closed balls centred at $x$ from $\tau_1$, then certain neighbourhoods of $x$ in $\tau_2$ (e.g. $\Bbb{Q}$) will not contain a closed ball.

If $B_x$ is a local basis of closed neighbourhoods from $\tau_2$, then as $\Bbb{Q}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, there must be a neighbourhood $W \in B_x$ of $x$, contained in $\Bbb{Q}$. Since $W$ is closed, we know that $W'$ is open, which is to say, $U, V \in \tau_1$ exist such that
$$W' = V \cup (U \cap \Bbb{Q}) \implies \Bbb{Q} \supseteq W = V' \cap (U' \cup \Bbb{Q}') = (V' \cap U') \cup (V' \cap \Bbb{Q}').$$
From this, we conclude that $V' \cap \Bbb{Q}' = \emptyset$, otherwise we obtain points from $\Bbb{Q}'$ in $\Bbb{Q}$. Thus, $W = V' \cap U'$, and hence $W$ is closed in $\tau_1$.

But, at the same time, $W$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, so there is an open set $A \cup (B \cap \Bbb{Q}) \in \tau_2$ that is contained in $W$, and which contains $x$. Given $W \subseteq \Bbb{Q}$, and $A \in \tau_1$, we see that $A = \emptyset$. The $\tau_1$-closure of $B \cap \Bbb{Q}$ must also be contained in $W$, since $W$ is $\tau_1$-closed, but this will contain irrational points by the $\tau_1$-density of $\Bbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R}$. This contradicts $W \subseteq \Bbb{Q}$.

So no, around rational points, there is no local base consisting of closed neighbourhoods.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time for the beautiful yet insightful explanation, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the add an open set topology.
In this case the set that is being added to the open sets of R is Q.

Given a space S and a set A, the smallest topology that includes A and the open sets of S is
{ $U \cup (V \cap A)$ : U,V open within S }.

Whereupon the closed sets, the complements, are
{ $K \cap (L - A)$ : K,L closed within S }.

Answer (score 1):

$0$ does not have a closed neighbourhood inside the open set $\Bbb Q$. It follows that this space is not regular, as I recently showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3177263/4280). Equivalently you cannot separate $0$ from the (closed) irrationals using disjoint open sets.